# To create JButton, JSlider and Graphics in a program file

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jcomponent

Help me to create a class file which consists of JButton and JSlider and Java Graphics.

I tried a lot of methods but not working in netbeans 7.2: Jpanel, Jcomponent, paint(), paintComponent().

Can any one give me a class file for example to create that one?

My code is here:

```
    package floating;
    import designs.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class Test extends JFrame
    {
        String frame_name;
        boolean START,PASS;
        int SPEED=1;
        JSlider jSlider1 = new javax.swing.JSlider();
        JSeparator js=new JSeparator();
        JToggleButton jToggleButton1 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton("START");
        JToggleButton jToggleButton2 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton("PASS");

        Test(String a)
        {

           JFrame jf=new JFrame(a);
            Dimension dim=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            jf.setSize(dim.width,dim.height-30);
            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(jf.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 


            js.setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
            js.setForeground(Color.red);
            js.setLocation(dim.width/2,0);
            js.setPreferredSize(dim);
            js.setSize(10,dim.height);
            jf.add(js);


            jSlider1.setLocation(dim.width-300,20);
            jSlider1.setSize(250,50);
            jSlider1.setToolTipText("Set to Seconds");
            jSlider1.setMinimum(1);jSlider1.setMaximum(5);jSlider1.setMajorTickSpacing(1);jSlider1.setMinorTickSpacing(1);jSlider1.setValue(1);
            jSlider1.setPaintLabels(true);
            jSlider1.setPaintTicks(true);
            jSlider1.setPaintTrack(true);
            jSlider1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                    jSlider1MouseClicked(evt);
                }
            });
            jf.add(jSlider1);

            jToggleButton1.setLocation((dim.width/2)+30,25);
            jToggleButton1.setSize(100,30);
            jToggleButton1.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
                public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                    jToggleButton1ItemStateChanged(evt);
                }
            });


            jToggleButton2.setLocation((dim.width/2)+50+100,25);
            jToggleButton2.setSize(100,30);
            jToggleButton2.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
                public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                    jToggleButton2ItemStateChanged(evt);
                }
            });


            jf.add(jToggleButton1);
            jf.add(jToggleButton2);


            jf.setLayout(null);  \\if layout is null the only all buttons and slider at positions and showing in JFrame 
            jf.setVisible(true);

        }

        public void jToggleButton1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) 
        {
            if(jToggleButton1.getActionCommand()=="START")
            {
                System.out.printf(jToggleButton1.getText());
                jToggleButton1.setText("STOP");
                this.START=true;
                System.out.println(this.START);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.printf(jToggleButton1.getText());
                jToggleButton1.setText("START");
                this.START=false;
                System.out.println(this.START);
            }
        }
        public void jToggleButton2ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) 
        {
            if( jToggleButton2.getActionCommand()=="PASS")
            {
                System.out.printf(jToggleButton2.getText());
                jToggleButton2.setText("RESUME");
                this.PASS=true;
                System.out.println("   "+this.PASS);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.printf(jToggleButton2.getText());
                jToggleButton2.setText("PASS");
                this.PASS=false;
                System.out.println( "  " +this.PASS);

            }
        }
        private void jSlider1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
        {

           this.SPEED=jSlider1.getValue();
           System.out.println(SPEED);
        }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Test a=new Test("Test");

        }
        public void paint(Graphics g) // for example but not shwowing in JFrame.
        {
             g.setColor(Color.red);
            RRectangle a=new RRectangle(60,100,250,190,60,60);
           a.drawShape(g);
           System.out.println(a);
        }

    }
```

Comment: PLs Add what U tried..??

Comment: Read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are section on `How to Use Buttons`, `How so Use Sliders`, `Custom Painting`. They all come with examples. So read the tutorial, download the example code and play with it. Then if you still have problems you can ask a specify question.

Comment: _"Help me to create a class file which consists of JButton and JSlider and Java Graphics."_ You have no explained what you expect these to do. So elaborate on _"not working"_

Comment: Try this problem and Tell me Please.

Comment: You can't do JButton and Graphics in Same class sure.Try Above Problem once and Tell me if it is right or Wrong not by looking

Comment: *"SEND THE FIXED CODE"*  1) Stop SHOUTING at us.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Your class extends JFrame, but then within your class you create an instance of JFrame and you add all the components to this instance of JFrame and make this frame visible. The extended class is never used or displayed.

So the paint() method that you override does nothing.

1. you should NOT be extending JFrame.
2. custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame

I gave you a link to the Swing tutorial in my comment above. Read the section on `Custom Painting` for a working example.